# Crop a UIImage to use with GLKTextureLoader

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimage, glkit, cgimageref

I am trying to crop an area out of a UIImage to use with GLKTextureLoader. I can set the texture directly using the the UIImage with the following:

```
- (void)setTextureImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSError *error;

    texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Texture Error:%@", error);
    } else {
        self.textureCoordinates[0] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 1.0f);
        self.textureCoordinates[1] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[2] = GLKVector2Make(0, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[3] = GLKVector2Make(0, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

However, if I try crop the image this way:

```
- (void)setTextureImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSError *error;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0f, 64.0f, 64.0f));
    texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:imageRef options:nil error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"[SF] Texture Error:%@", error);
    } else {
        self.textureCoordinates[0] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 1.0f);
        self.textureCoordinates[1] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[2] = GLKVector2Make(0, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[3] = GLKVector2Make(0, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Texture Error:Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 12.)" UserInfo=0x6a6b550 {GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=Image decoding failed}
```

How can I take a section of the UIImage to use as a texture with GLKTextureLoader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I got it to work with UIImagePNGRepresentation, I'm only learning OpenGL/GLKit at the moment - so not an expert but I'm guessing the CGImage was missing some colorspace or some other data that is required for textures.

```
- (void)setTextureImage:(UIImage *)image withFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSError *error;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef])];

    texture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"[SF] Texture Error:%@", error);
    } else {
        self.textureCoordinates[0] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 1.0f);
        self.textureCoordinates[1] = GLKVector2Make(1.0f, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[2] = GLKVector2Make(0, 0);
        self.textureCoordinates[3] = GLKVector2Make(0, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem, do you have a better solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.It seems like this bug comes from that I redraw the image.

It will come out,if I create the CGContext like this:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault|kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

However,it will load texture successfully,if I create the CGContext like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aImage.size, NO, aImage.scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error because of incorrect alpha settings for an CGImageRef.
The documentation for GLKTextureLoader lists the supported CGImage formats in Table 1.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GLKTextureLoader/textureWithCGImage%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)

I've changed code used to create context from

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * (CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(space) + 1), space, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

to

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, width * (CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(space) + 1), space, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

Everything is fine for me now. And this should fix Feng Stone's problem.
For you I would recommend to skip `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` function and create a new CGContext with correct parameters, where you can draw your image with `CGContextDrawImage`